# WS-Security: X.509 Certificate Token Profile 1.1 & Biztalk

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding, x509

I need to communicate via BizTalk WCF Adapter (probably Custom or WSHttp) with a webservice secured with WS-Security: X.509 Certificate Token Profile 1.1

The requirement are below (taken from SoapUI):

Key Identifier: Issuer Name and Serial Number 
Signature Algorithm: xmldsig#rsa-sha1
 Signature Canonicalization: xml-exc-c14n#
 Digest Algorithm: xmlenc#sha256 
Use Single Certificate: true

Does anyone have any idea how to translate this requirements to BizTalk WCF Custom adapter?

Comment: That would depend on how the cert is implemented on the webservice.  Is it configured to secure the transport layer or to decrypt encrypted messages?

Comment: webservice expects a message just signed but not encrypted